# How to convert jQuery to JavaScript name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, dom-events

I'm trying to find a way to create 'on click' events for dynamically generated buttons in JS. I know that in jQuery it can be done like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'name=[buttonName]', function() {});
```

I know the e.target method in JS, but I'm wanting to find a way to do it with a name attribute instead.

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you want ? document.getElementsByName("buttonName")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly that line of jQuery isn't quite right as the square brackets are in the wrong place:

```
$(document).on('click', '[name="buttonName"]', func);
```

To achieve the same in plain JS you would need to attach a click event handler to a static parent element, then check the `name` property of the clicked element:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.name == 'buttonName') {
    // do something...
  }
});
```

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.name == 'buttonName') {
    alert('Hello!');
  }
});
```

```html
<button>I do nothing!</button>
<button name="buttonName">I say hello!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelector` in a similar way than you would in jQuery, and attach the event listener whenever a new element is added to the DOM.

```js
document.querySelector("button[name='buttonName']").addEventListener("click", function(){
   alert("Hello, World");
});
```

```html
<button name="buttonName">Click me</button>
```

The difference to the original jQuery code is that in that example it listens to events on the `document` whereas this does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getElementByName to add click event to your button which is dynamically render

```
document.getElementByName("ButtonName").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
});
```